# rjags - implementing a weighted multivariate normal distribution

Tags: r, multivariate-normal-distribution, jags, weighted

I am trying to implement a weighted multivariate normal distribution in JAGS 4.3.0
Here is the code I used:

```
for (i in 1:N){ 
    y_stage1[i, 1:T] ~ dmnorm(mu_stage1[i, 1:T], 
    Sigma_stage1_weighted[i, 1:T, 1:T])
    Sigma_stage1_weighted[i, 1:T, 1:T] <- 
            Sigma_stage1[1:T, 1:T] * propensity_score[i]
}
Sigma_stage1 ~ dwish(R, df)
df = 6
```

In Rstudio, the input for R is:

```
R = structure(as.vector(diag(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Dim = c(5, 5))
```

and `T = 5`

The error message says:"error in node Sigma_stage1, unable to find appropriate sampler"

I am not sure how to debug the code.